# Need to convert ksh command line to sh

Tags: sh

I'm trying to do a simple operation in `ksh` that I need to repeat in `sh` (Bourne shell)

All I want to do is append the contents of the first line of hte pay_period.txt file to the end of the new file name. This works great in ksh, but does not work in bourne.  The program I'm using defaults to `sh` and I can't change that. Also I can't have actual shell scipts in the directories. So I have to issue commands.

How can I make the equivalent command below work in bourne

```
mv HEPAY.txt HE_PAY"$(/usr/bin/head -1 pay_period.txt)."txt
```

The results of `$(/usr/bin/head -1 pay_period.txt)` is `20140101`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really talking about a real Bournce shell then you need to use backticks for command substitution (`$()` is POSIX and portable among "modern", POSIX-compliant shells but won't work in old, legacy shells), e.g.

```
mv HEPAY.txt HE_PAY`/usr/bin/head -1 pay_period.txt`.txt
```

Other than that I see no reason why this should not work.

PS: Note that `head -1` isn't POSIX-compliant either (`head -n 1` is).